# Open bootstrap collapse by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have a form that when it submits I validate some required inputs. If any of the these required inputs is empty, I open a modal showing a message that they are required. 
My problem is that in the close button of the modal I call a JS function that scroll my page to the top, hide all the bootstrap panels, and open the bootstrap panel #collapse2 (That panel has the required fields).

```
function closeAlerts() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
    $(".collapse").collapse("hide");
    $("#collapse2").collapse("show");
}
```

The first time that I submit my form, it works perfect (show the modal with the required fields message, close it and keep only the #collapse2 opened).In the second time, show the modal with the messages, but do not open the #collapse2.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like some markup or a full demo is required here.

Comment: Agree, seeing a demo would be helpful. From what I am seeing I am wondering if you have a conflict. You are collapsing all of the panels and then opening one of them. Maybe change the hide to not include the #collapse2 so there isn't a conflict with closing and opening it at the same time it is animating. `$(".collapse:not(#collapse2)").collapse("hide");

Comment: Also, are you getting any errors in the console? I just tested in console and got Error: Collapse is transitioning ... when I called show and hide together.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you

The solution for me was add:

```
$(".collapse:not(#collapse2)").collapse("hide");
```